# How to allow double only data type in textbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform, where users are supposed to enter measured dimensions of a part (Quality Management field) into checkboxes. This means no text is allowed, neither some random digits, only numbers.

What I have now, is this:

```
Private Sub TextBox25_AfterUpdate()    
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox25.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Invalid data!"
        TextBox25.BackColor = RGB(255, 200, 200)
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

It's not perfect though, user still can type in some random digits like `09` instead of `0,9` and get no error message. I believe allowing only double-type data is the key but I tried the code below and it does not work (I get the error message every time, no matter the data type). Any ideas?

```
Private Sub TextBox19_AfterUpdate()
    If Not VarType(TextBox19.Value) = vbDouble Then
        MsgBox "Invalid data!"
        TextBox19.BackColor = RGB(255, 200, 200)
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use a regular expression. Use `CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This will limit entires at runtime :)

```
'~~> Prevent anything other than numbers and decimals
Private Sub TextBox19_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete, _
        vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
            If KeyAscii = 46 Then If InStr(1, TextBox19.Text, ".") Then KeyAscii = 0
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
End Sub

'~~> Allow only decimals
Private Sub TextBox19_AfterUpdate()
    If Int(Val(TextBox19.Value)) = TextBox19.Value And _
    InStr(1, TextBox19.Value, ".") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid data!"
        TextBox19.BackColor = RGB(255, 200, 200)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note**: If you do not want to allow `9.0` then remove `InStr(1, TextBox19.Value, ".") = 0` in the `_AfterUpdate()`

**AND** If you want to disable the inputs like `0x.xx` then you can use this as well

```
Private Sub TextBox19_AfterUpdate()
    If Int(Val(TextBox19.Value)) = TextBox19.Value And _
       InStr(1, TextBox19.Value, ".") = 0 Or _
       (Left(TextBox19.Value, 1) = 0 And Mid(TextBox19.Value, 2, 1) <> ".") Then
        MsgBox "Invalid data!"
        TextBox19.BackColor = RGB(255, 200, 200)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But this will allow `09` as input which the OP didn't want to allow. This does not force a decimal seperator.

Comment: Hope it is ok now? :)

Comment: Not sure. This would not allow `9,0` because it is an integer that was inputted as decimal. The OP is not clear about if it just need to be inputted as decimal like `9,0` or if he doesn't allow integer values at all.

Comment: How about now? :)

Comment: The point is to avoid letters and accidental digits like 09.

So allowed entries are:

9
0,9
9,0

Although it would be nice to convert 9 into 9,0/9.0 automatically

Comment: @DawidW If you allow `9` `0,9` `9,0` what is the difference between `9` and  `09`? both is numerical `9`, there is no difference in its value. Also if you are talking about *"convert `9` into `9,0`/`9.0`"* this doesn't make sense because numerical `9` and `9.0` are exactly the same there is no difference.

Comment: @DawidW: The above code will not let you type a letter. As far as 09 is concerned,  I have updated the post. have a look now...

Comment: Ok, I gave it a go and it works well enough, perffectly actually. Thank so much!

Answer (score 2):

The `.Value` of a TextBox is always a `String` the name "TextBox" already includes that it is "Text". So it cannot be of type `Double` unless you take that `String` and convert it (implicit or explicit) into a `Double`.

`VarType(TextBox19.Value)` will always return `vbString` because it returns the type of the variable not the type of the data inside the variable.

So you actually need to test if it is decimal (not a integer).

The only way to test this properly is to check if the `String` contains exactly one `,` (respective `.` depending on your localization). And then test if this is numeric (otherwise it would accept `a,b` too).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestForDecimalInput()
    Dim DecimalValue As Double
    Dim TextBoxValue As String

    TextBoxValue = "9" 'just for testing get your text box value here: TextBoxValue = TextBox19.Value

    'this replaces . and , with the actual decimal seperator of your operating system
    'so the user is allowed to either enter `0,9` or `0.9`
    TextBoxValue = Replace$(TextBoxValue, ".", Application.DecimalSeparator)
    TextBoxValue = Replace$(TextBoxValue, ",", Application.DecimalSeparator)

    'Check if there is exactly one! decimal seperator
    If Len(TextBoxValue) = Len(Replace$(TextBoxValue, Application.DecimalSeparator, "")) + 1 Then

        'we need to check for numeric too because yet it could be `a,b` too
        If IsNumeric(TextBoxValue) Then
            DecimalValue = CDbl(TextBoxValue)
        End If
    End If

    If DecimalValue <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print TextBoxValue, "->", DecimalValue
    Else
        Debug.Print TextBoxValue, "->", "Invalid Data"
    End If
End Sub
```

This would be the result of some example inputs

```
0.9           ->             0,9 
09            ->            Invalid Data
0,9           ->             0,9 
0,9,0         ->            Invalid Data
0,0           ->            Invalid Data
9,0           ->             9 
9             ->            Invalid Data
```

Note that `9,0` will be accepted as input but `9` will be invalid as input.

Comment: Hope this will not discourage You but being a total noob I am not sure how am I supposed to use this code. 

I created a module, modified TextBoxValue = 9 into TextBoxValue=Textbox19.value but it does not seem to do anything. A believe I have to activate it somehow whithin my userform, am i right?

Comment: Look into the immediate window `Debug.Print` just prints it there.

Comment: I tried the other solution and it worked on p&p basis so I am gonna stick to that. Thank You very much anyway!

Comment: ++ @Pᴇʜ I had no intention of "sniping" your answer. Just felt that, what OP asked could be handled in a different way. My sincere apologies M8.

Comment: @SiddharthRout no worries ^^ I always like to see alternative ways and I think we are both not here because of the points ;)